# Notify sender of new email address, when it's a Gmail alias

Tags: email, gmail, alias, google-workspace

I have a G Suite account for, let's say, `domain.com`. I have a user with email address `me@domain.com`. Today I added a new domain to the account `new-domain.com` and set up an email alias for my user, which is `me@new-domain.com`.

Since "New Domain" is my new company name, I want to transition to the new email address and eventually get rid of the old one. To help avoid confusion during this transition, I want anyone who emails the old address (`me@domain.com`) to get an auto-response like "Please use my new email address in the future...".

**What I've Tried**

The most obvious thing would be to setup a Vacation Responder, but Gmail doesn't let you specify which address it's for. So there's no way for me to easily specify that responses should only be going to senders emailing `me@domain.com`. G Suite does have an advanced setting in Gmail where you can quarantine messages. I've tried to use that to quarantine Vacation Responders coming from the new address, but that's not working either because the new address is now the default one, and thus emails coming in to `me@domain.com` get a Vacation Responder from `me@new-domain.com`.

To me, this seems like a pretty common situation - transitioning users from one domain to another - and using an alias so users can just have one inbox to check. Does anyone know how to get this to work, or is there some other best practice I could be following?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, your options are to use the Gmail Routing to block incoming mail to specific users or groups and to set it to 'reject message' and add a message informing them of this change.

-a little crude but workable.

Alternatively ensure users reply use their new primary email and ensure there is a long enough transition period for people for external responders to change over.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately adding a block to the incoming mail and expecting the sender to resend to the new email address would be a less than ideal experience. The latter is essentially what we went with. I'm still a little at a loss for how other people have handled this relatively common situation.